# installation failed loopback cli on windows npm install -g loopback-cli

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

Trying to install loopback lead me to this error..can anyone help to clear out this.. [you can see the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNjmU.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the error? It can be solved by installing .Net Framework 2.0 SDK and installing Visual Studio 2005 or adding the location of the component to the system if it's installed elsewhere.

Anyway, here's how to [install it on windows](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Installing-on-Windows.html), if you're missing out on something.